# Setting Date Picker to select a Birthdate in the past MaterializeCss

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am trying to use MaterializeCss date-picker form field to set a birthday.

```
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
```

is what i am currently using, however this gives a total of 15 years in total 7 years before todays year and 7 years after. how can I only allow for present year - 80 years for example..

if I do something like:

```
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: -15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
```

the year menu totally disappears.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max` property to limit the date range to the current year, [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/mobabur94/jv8m9cw2/).

```
var date = new Date();
var today = '12/31/' + date.getFullYear();

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 15,
  max: today,
});
```

Also see http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/ for more options.

Comment: works great! Thanks so much for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

you can just set `max` field to `true`
then datepicker will hide rest of days from today

```html
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 99, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
      max: true,
      today: 'Today',
      clear: 'Clear',
      close: 'Ok'
});
```